# When using UISearchController to search TableView, only the title is shown as a result and not the accompanying image and url

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a table with a list of items. Each cell has the item title, a background image and a url which is opened when the cell is clicked.

I have a working search function which searches through the titles and the table it creates is updated with the items that match the search criteria. Unfortunately, only the titles show in the searchResults tableView and nothing happens when the updated cells are clicked. I don't know how to make the accompanying images show for the cells or the urls.

I believe the problem is because I am only searching through the titles and populating the searchResults array that makes up the content of the searchResults table with the searched titles and this ignores the accompanying images and urls. I'm not sure how to include the title, image and url just by searching the title.

The information comes from a json with a format:

```
{
    "items":
        [
            {
                "title":"title1",
                "url":"url1",
                "thumbnail":"thumbnailURL1"
            },

            {
                "title":"title2",
                "url":"url2",
                "thumbnail":"thumbnailURL2"
            }
        ]
}
```

The rest of my code looks like this:

#### WikiViewController.m (table to be searched)

```
#import "WikiViewController.h"
#import "NavigationViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "WikiSearchResultsViewController.h"


@interface WikiViewController () <NSURLSessionDataDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSURLSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *jsonArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *controller;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *results;

@end


@implementation WikiViewController


#pragma mark - viewDid...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" ];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(searchButtonPressed:)];


    WikiSearchResultsViewController *searchResults = (WikiSearchResultsViewController *)self.controller.searchResultsController;
    [self addObserver:searchResults forKeyPath:@"results" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

}

# pragma mark - Search Results Updater


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    // filter the search results
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text];
    self.results = [[self.jsonArray valueForKey:@"title"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}

- (void)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    // present the search controller
    [self presentViewController:self.controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (UISearchController *)controller {

    if (!_controller) {

        // instantiate search results table view
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Wiki" bundle:nil];
        WikiSearchResultsViewController *resultsController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchResults"];

        // create search controller
        _controller = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:resultsController];
        _controller.searchResultsUpdater = self;

        // optional: set the search controller delegate
        _controller.delegate = self;

    }
    return _controller;
}



#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.jsonArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *item = self.jsonArray[indexPath.row];

    if (![item[@"thumbnail"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:item[@"thumbnail"]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
        UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

        [bgImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [bgImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

        cell.backgroundView = bgImageView;
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"title"];


    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *item = self.jsonArray[indexPath.row];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baseurl.com"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:item[@"url"] relativeToURL:baseURL];

    webViewController.URL = URL;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController
                                         animated:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Creating NSURLSession

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                                 delegate:self
                                            delegateQueue:nil];
        [self fetchFeed];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://www.requeststring.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                         NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                                                      error:nil];
                                                         self.jsonArray = jsonObject[@"items"];

                                                         NSLog(@"%@", self.jsonArray);

                                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.tableView reloadData];
                                                         });
                                                     }];
    [dataTask resume];
}

@end
```

#### WikiSearchResultsViewController.m (search results table view)

```
#import "WikiSearchResultsViewController.h"
#import "WikiViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WikiSearchResultsViewController () <NSURLSessionDataDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *searchResults;

@property (nonatomic) NSURLSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *jsonArray;

@end


@implementation WikiSearchResultsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                             delegate:self
                                        delegateQueue:nil];

    [self fetchFeed];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.searchResults.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *item in _jsonArray){
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baseurl.com"];
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:item[@"url"] relativeToURL:baseURL];

        webViewController.title = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        webViewController.URL = URL;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController
                                             animated:YES];
    }



}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

    // extract array from observer
    self.searchResults = [(NSArray *)object valueForKey:@"results"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



#pragma mark - Creating NSURLSession

- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://www.requeststring.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                         NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                                                      error:nil];
                                                         self.jsonArray = jsonObject[@"items"];

                                                         NSLog(@"%@", self.jsonArray);

                                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.tableView reloadData];
                                                         });
                                                     }];
    [dataTask resume];
}


@end
```

Comment: Can you whittle down the code you're putting here to what you think is most relevant? It's a bit much to try and read through your entire class to pull out the tasty bits.

Comment: Of course, I've removed some of the most irrelevant bits. What's left are the sections which set up the tables, the search features and the method fetchFeed() which retrieves the json. There's still probably some bits which aren't too helpful but I wasn't sure what would be useful to see or not.